# Ajax call on form submit in Grails 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, grails

I am using Grails 2.4. I have g:formRemote (Grails custom form). Inside that form I have a dropdown list. On form submission button I called a JQuery function. Inside that function I am calling Ajax.

Form submission is not occurring. I can't get dropdown value inside my controller. My form submission and Ajax call is directing to same controller and same method.

Upon selecting an item from dropdown menu and submitting the form I need a data table which has values according to that selection.

```
Form:
 <g:formRemote name="searchForm" id="searchFormId" url="[controller: 
    'GeneratedLetterController', action: 'getFolderlist']"
    onComplete="onComplete()"   class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
 <g:select class="form-control" name="projectCode" from="${session.projectList}" 
      optionValue="ProjName" optionKey="ProjID"  id="projectCode" noSelection="
      ['': '----------Select----------']" required=""/>
  <g:field type="submit" name="submitB1" class="btn btn-primary"  onClick="openDtable()"
   value="${message(code: 'common.label.select')}"/>
 </g:formRemote>

Jquery ajax:
 function openDtable(projCode) {

            x.style.display = '';
            table = $('#projectDetailsTable').DataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "pageLength": 10,   //per_page
                "bServerSide": true,
                "scrollX": true,
                "searching": false,
                "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                "sAjaxSource": "${createLink(controller:'GeneratedLetter',action:'getFolderlist')}",

             "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "<center>No records available</center>"
                },

                "aoColumns": [
                    {"data": "RunID"},
                    {"data": "Create_dt"}
                ]
            })
        }
```

Comment: Provide you relevant code.

Comment: As i am out of my office i can only share my code by tomarrow

Comment: gsp and action ( for ajax call) should be different, declare the separate action for ajax in your controller

Comment: Use simple html form instead of <g:formRemote>, call function on form submit button click which will have ajax implementation.

Comment: i cant use two buttons,one for form submission and one for ajax call.Do i have to pass the  form value through ajax call and avoid form submission?

Comment: don't use two buttons simply use single, keep  type "button" instead of "submit", collect form data in your js and pass that to ajax call.